# Passing value types by reference

Tags: c#, parameters, heap-memory, value-type, stack-memory

I'm in the process of learning about reference types, value types, the stack and the heap and the differences between them.

Now I've ran into something that's a bit mind-boggling to me. Here's a code example to illustrate what I mean

```
void Main()
{
  int foo = 0;
  PassFoo(ref foo);
  Console.WriteLine(foo);
}
void PassFoo(ref int bar) 
{
  bar = 1;
}
```

As it stands now the output would be `1` as long as we use the *ref* keyword. If we remove the *ref* keyword then the output will be `0`. I understand that this is because *integers* are *value types* and when we pass `foo` by value we are copying the value bit by bit to `bar` but when we add the *ref* keyword we are instead passing only the memory adress of `foo` on the stack and that is also why we're changing the value of `foo` in this example. Am I right so far?

... Now to the part that confuses me. My understanding of how the stack works is that it can only access the currently running stack frame. That's why `PassFoo` can't directly access `foo`. I have also learned that *value types* are stored where they are declared. So this is what confuses me, when we're passing `foo` by reference we're passing the memory adress of `foo` to `bar` right? But shouldn't this be inaccessible to `PassFoo()` because it is running in a different stack frame?

I realize that I probably don't quite have the right understanding of how this works, so a clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Variables in higher stack frames are still accessible in nested method calls, so there's no problem with taking their address. The problems occur when you try to return a pointer to a local in a method which has returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding of how the stack works is that it can only access the currently running stack frame.

That's not true.  Under the hood, a method is able to access the memory from any stack frame.  The C# compiler simply applies constraints such that, in most situations, references to locations on the stack are not exposed outside of that method's body.  This situation, the use of the `ref` keyword, is one exception to that situation.  Once you get to lower layers of abstraction, namely the IL code that the compiler generates, there is no constraint at all that would prohibit accessing a stack from another method's body.

The first half of your question is a valid explanation as to what's going on.

Comment: Right, I realized that my understanding probably wasn't 100% accurate. So basically what you're saying is that, there's no actual limitation when it comes to a method accessing memory in other stack frames but the limitations imposed by the compiler, but in this case since we are using the *ref* keyword the compiler won't apply those contraints?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive Pretty much.  The reason that you can't usually access the stack frame of another method body is because local methods are not accessible outside of their method's body (hence why they're local), and most other means of grabbing onto an address to something that would be in the stack frame is either prohibited, or hoists the local variable into something not on the stack (i.e. closures) rather than allowing reference to the stack to escape the method body.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass foo into PassFoo you are passing the address of where foo resides. Since PassFoo knows where the value of foo is stored, it can change the value in that memory address. The stack frame for PassFoo contains only the address of the variable. The following is equivalent C code with pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PassFoo(int* bar)
{
    *bar = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int foo = 0;
    PassFoo(&foo);
    printf("%d", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method calls another method then the new method creates its stack frame on the top of the stack. In this way each new method can allocate its own local variables in its own portion of the memory allocated to the stack, and stack is also use to store parameters and return values passed between methods, that's why it the pointer to foo that is stored in bar parameter is visible.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really true. My understand is that we can't directly access `foo`, because we didn't know the **reference**(in c#) or **address**(in c). Think about we are programming in c, you can access any memory. So we use pass by reference, than we could access the value of foo by the reference. You can think stack frame as physical function chunk to manipulate memory and function easier.

Here's an article about [stack.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)

Answer (score -2):

Your understanding is quite good. Passing a value type by reference will cause the framework to box that parameter, i.e. wrapping a reference to it in an object that is created on the heap. I am not sure what you mean by "stack frame". Both methods ("Main" and "PassFoo") would have access to the same stack.

Comment: Passing by ref does not require boxing.